# File format not included in file name when saved in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason when I upload a document and store the file name in mysql table the file name extension isn't included in the name. For example, I upload the pdf file "car.pdf" and the way it is stored in mysql table is "car."(see period right after the word, The file extension is not included). I have checked this website, I have googled it too, but can't find a clear answer.

```
    $doc_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_FILES['doc']['name']));
    $doc_type = $_FILES['doc']['type'];
    $doc_size = $_FILES['doc']['size'];
            if(!empty($title)){
            if(!empty($doc_name)){
                if (($doc_type == 'application/pdf') || ($doc_type == 'application/msword') || ($doc_type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')){
                    if(($doc_size > 0) && ($doc_size <= FILE_MAXFILESIZE)){
                        if ($_FILES['doc']['error'] == 0) {
                        $final_name = time() . $doc_name;
                        $target = $uploadpath . $final_name;
                            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
                                $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die ('There was a problem with your query. Please, contact administrator'); 

                                if(!empty($description)){
                                $query = "INSERT INTO uploaded_files (file, title, description, date_time, user_id, dep_id) VALUES ('$final_name', '$title', '$description', now(), '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "', '$dep_id')";
                                }.... rest of the code goes here
```

Comment: That's weird. What column type do you have on `file` that receives the file name? And what's the LENGTH?

Comment: the column type and length are varchar(32)

Comment: And have you confirmed that the LENGTH of the path you're inserting (i.e. string length) isn't longer than 32?

Comment: I think that just solved the problem.... THANKS A LOT! what dumb mistake!

Comment: If you've confirmed that this issue is hereby solved, then shall I make an official answer for your acceptance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL could truncate the string you're inserting, if the length of the string exceeds what you have in the column definition. In this case, check that the file path name does not have a string name longer than 32.

Ordinarily, one would expect this INSERT query to fail, but it may not do so if the configuration settings permit.

If the mysql configuration is under your control (and you desire to avoid this kind of silent truncation of inserted string), start by adding `strict_trans_tables` to the `sql_mode` settings in your `my.ini` (OR `my.conf`) file.

Best of luck.